# Do I need a ETL tool for Enterprise Integrations?

Tags: apex, integration, enterprise

I have worked with five end to End Integration using Several ETL tools like IBM integation bus, Informatica , Mule soft, Cast Iron, SAP PI etc.,, Some times the clients are having a little cash crunch to Invest in ETL tool. I have advocated benefits of using an ETL for their data integration with respect to ease of maintenance,  Reduce the strain of data processing in Source and Target systems etc., but some time these advises need to come from someone who has higher pay check than me. They will never buy my advices. What should be the technical pitch I should put forth to business, product owner, Sponsor when I grow higher up in the chain. Please suggest.
What are the advantages of using a direct data connection rather than taking ETL route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two main factors to using third party ETL: time to release, and support. If time isn't a contributing factor, and you have dedicated developers and IT to support a project, the total TCO will often be lower in the long run.

The main downside to most ETL is that you're giving up some control of your data to the provider, and you almost always have to weaken your security controls and/or access rules to your data or network. You might also be prohibited legally from exporting your data to a ETL provider.

I've worked for several companies that preferred internal development to third party services so they could control access and security controls, as well as enjoy a lower TCO overall.

There are certainly benefits to using third party when it makes sense, but most simple integrations don't need the extra support, and aren't that time sensitive. It's always worth taking the time to assess the situation and consider if a third party solution is the right one.

Comment: another downside - one often contracts with a specialist ETL vendor to do the setup and config; but once the project is over, said vendor is no longer on contract and if the ETL is a complicated tool (e.g. as mentioned in OP), no one in org has a clue how to adjust/customize